# How to sort ps output to find processes realtime priority and identify processess currently occupied running queue

Tags: process, cpu, ps, real-time, priority

How to properly identify real-time processes currently occupied CPU queue and count them using ps? I know there is a bunch of fileds like prio,rtprio,pri,nice but do not know correct to use. It seems I need use something like `ps -eo rtprio,prio,cpu,cmd --sort=+rtprio` to get full list, but it do not seems for me right since a lot of processes got with `-` sign at RTPRIO column. For example, I have 48 cores system running Oracle Linux and try to identify following questions:

1. What processes occupied run queue? What's a count of them?
2. How to identify processes that run in Real Time mode or with increased priority?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list of non-zero CPU % processes:

```
ps -eo pid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat,wchan:14,comm --sort=+pcpu | awk '$8!=0.0 {print}' | awk 'NR>1'
```

To count them

```
ps -eo pid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat,wchan:14,comm --sort=+pcpu | awk '$8!=0.0 {print}' | awk 'NR>1' | wc -l
```

To see this continuously updated, but them in a file called `processes.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -eo pid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat,wchan:14,comm --sort=+pcpu | awk '$8!=0.0 {print}' | awk 'NR>1'
```

and make it executable with `chmod +x processes.sh`.  Now run it with watch for live updating:

```
watch ./processes.sh
```

Comment: Hi, I see also their scheduling pripority (i.e. class). Does it mean processess without RR and FF value in ps column recognized as not realtime?